# Is ${\rm Sym}(X)$ countable if $X$ is countable?

Tags: group-theory, functions, symmetric-groups, infinity

> Is ${\rm Sym}(X)$ countable if $X$ is countable?

I tried to write all elements in order, like pick the first element as the permutation with the smallest $f(1)$.

If there are several permutations with the same $f(1)$, pick the one with the smallest $f(2)$, or $f(3)$..., then do the same thing to pick the second, the third element and so on.

I wonder if this shows that ${\rm Sym}(X)$ is countable.

Comment: For every subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$, there is at least one permutation that fixes exactly the elements of $A$. You can define one by $f(x)=x$ for $x\in A$ and $f(x)$, for $x\in \mathbb{N}\setminus A$ to be the smallest element in $(\mathbb{N}\setminus A)\setminus\{1,2,...,x\}$.

Comment: @flan this construction is not a permutation. Actually, for a subset $A$ there is a permutation that fixes exactly elements of $A$ if and only if $A$ is not the complement of a singleton (exercise).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the symmetric group of an infinite set $X$ is always uncountable, and actually has cardinality $2^{|X|}$.

It is easy to see that it has at least that cardinality, since we can define a surjection $\operatorname{Sym}(X)\to \mathcal{P}(X)$ by sending $f$ to the set of its fixed points. This is surjective since for any subset $Y\subset X$, you can define a symmetry $f$ of $X$ by setting it to the identity on $Y$, and any permutation without fixed points on $X\setminus Y$. (You can try to prove that such a permutation always exist on any set.)

Comment: Sorry I am confused with the map $\operatorname{Sym}(X)\to \mathcal{P}(X)$, can u explain it more clearly?

Comment: I don't know if I can be much more explicit. It takes some $f\in \operatorname{Sym}(X)$, and returns the set $Y\subset X$ of the fixed points of $f$ (that is, $Y=\{x\in X\,|\, f(x)=x\}$).

Comment: This is almost surjective: no such permutation exists if $Y$ is the complement of a singleton.