# Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets such that $|A| = |B|$, prove that the set of all bijections from $A$ to $B$ is uncountable

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, set-theory

According to Cantor's definition of same-cardinality, the set of all bijections from $A$ to $B$ must be non-empty. And we also know that for finite sets $A$ and $B$, the set of all bijections from $A$ to $B$ must have cardinality $|B|!$ , which is finite since $|B| \in  \mathbb{Z}_{\geq{0}}$ is finite.

But how do we argue for **infintie** sets? Evidently, the previous argument cannot be extended for infinite sets $A$ and $B$ since $|B|$ by itself is **undefined**.

Either we must prove that a subset of the set of bijections from the set $A$ to $B$ is uncountable, and hence conclude that the entire set of bijections from $A$ to $B$ is uncountable or do something similar.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer to the following post answers your question [Is ${\rm Sym}(X)$ countable if $X$ is countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559879/is-rm-symx-countable-if-x-is-countable) and gives more information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AnneBauval! Actually they are talking about $\sum_{X}$ where it is the symmetric group on X. Hence they are talking about the set of bijections from a set to itself. Nonetheless thank you for pointing this out also, I will take a look.

Comment: Regarding cardinalities it is exactly the same! Any bijection between $A$ and $B$ induces naturally a bijection between $Bij(A,B)$ and $Bij(A,A).$

Comment: Ah yes you are right indeed! Thank you @AnneBauval